# How to publish a table in Geoserver 2.4.x, so that only specific users can access it

Tags: geoserver, xml, publishing

I want to publish some tables in GeoServer 2.4.x so that it is restricted to some particular users.  Right now, I have tables that is public to all users.
I have a web app, through which I am accessing GeoServer and downloading the table data.But it will be user specific.Eg: If I login to the web app, the app will only display the tables that is accessible to me. The user authentication is done too. Only, how to make the tables user specific, so that the getcapabilities query return the tables specific to that user.Right now, this query:
http://weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

returns the xml file containing all the tables.

Can you help me out ?